# retrieving values of order_id,store name etc in Thank you page of ecommerce site for GA

Tags: google-analytics, e-commerce

How to get the order id, store name values etc to add in _addtrans() method in thank you page of the eCommerce site.Tutorial explained the syntax and examples but they kept mum on how to and from where to get those values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They need to be provided by the shop software (that is the shops needs to render the values into the javascript block). Since these values need to be shown to the visitor who has bought your stuff those variables should be available on an order confirmation page.

If you cannot change the serverside code but know the markup of the page you can write a javascript that retrieves the values from the DOM.

I.e. if the orderid is rendered inside a div like that:

> < div id="orderid" >Order12345< /div >

you can get the value (example assumes jQuery):

> myid = $('#orderid').text();
>
> _gaq.push(['_addTrans',
>
> ```
>   myid, // orderid retrieved via js           
>  ...
> ```
>
> ]);

So one way or the other the data needs to come from your shopping system.